# Outlook's address book shows no results if searhed by name

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2013

I know I have a specific contact in my Outlook's 2013 address book.
If I enter their name in the **address book** Outlook won't find anything, **but** if I enter the email address of that contact Outlook find it with proper name.

Is there some setting I need to change to make Outlook work with name searches?

Answer (score 0):

I think by default the address book search will only look at last name.  When you have the address book open, try changing the Search setting from "Name only" to "More columns".  That will search by first name and possibly other columns depending on what information is available.

There's also the Advanced Find option.

Comment: Will try and report back.